# Having to use full file path for import statements in React

Tags: reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

I have never ran into this problem in the past when working on a new React project. For some reason, I have to import modules from their full path name to make them work.

Here is an example:

```
import {
  List,
  ListItem,
} from 'react-md/lib/Lists';
import { Avatar } from 'react-md/lib/Avatars';
```

In the past, I have been able to do this without any extra work.

```
import {
  Avatar,
  List,
  ListItem,
} from 'react-md';
```

Project structure:

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
    components/
      AllOfMyComponentsAreHere
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post your webpack config? Specifically the resolver section? Or whatever else you are using to compile this?

Comment: I am not using webpack. This is just a new project built with npm install -g create-react-app.

Comment: `create-react-app` uses webpack under the hood, which resolves to certain root folders. Could you please post your file structure then?

Comment: @iHowell I added my project structure.

Comment: Hmm, something must have gone wrong in the setup. You should have to just import from `components/`. This is a bit odd. Try doing that and see what you come up with. It is possible it linked in a weird way.

Comment: I suppose that I could just create a new project and move my components directory to the new project.

Comment: So, I think I know what's up. The create-react-tools probably also made an `index.js(x)` file that imported all the components and exported them, which is the only way I can explain how you can import all the components from one file. You can do the same thing in your components folder if you want. You shouldn't need anything before the src folder when importing though. Try it out and let us know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163752/discussion-between-ihowell-and-jake-stewart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error that occurred while the project was being created. To solve the problem, I created a new project, installed my needed dependencies and copied my components directory to the new project.

Thanks for the help iHowell.